# PHP ERROR, DVMA master Config.ini.php error

Tags: php

I want to run DVMA-master but got an error. here is the error

```
DVWA System error - config file not found. Copy config/config.inc.php.dist to config/config.inc.php and configure to your environment.
```

I'll try [this solution](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/issues/150) but not work for me. `localhost/` is working and `phpmyadmin` is also working. I also try to copy using : `Sudo cp` in terminal but not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It literally tells you what to do.

- Copy the file config/config.inc.php.dist
- Paste in the same place, remove the `.dist` from the end
- Edit your new file

Good luck!